# Add running docker container into a virtual network

Tags: docker, networking, traefik, virtual-network

I've an already running docker container which I do not want to restart. Now I want to use [traefik](https://traefik.io) as a reverse proxy to access that already runner container. For that both containers need to share the same virtual (docker) network: `proxy`

```
# docker run ... --name gui vendor/image:tag
# docker network create proxy
# docker run ... --network proxy traefik:alpine --docker
```

The question is: Can the `gui` container join the `proxy` network? And if so? How do I join that network?

Answer (score 0):

Just found it myself from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#extended-description):

```
docker network connect proxy gui
```